# Instant messaging not working in Tuleap

Tags: tuleap

I have recently installed Tuleap in a VPS. But when I see that when I go to instant messaging page, it opens a pop-up and says "Service unavailable".

When I go to instant messaging plugin administration, it says the following-

```
WARNING: If you synchronize one or several groups here, you will have to restart the Openfire server by executing "service openfire restart" as root in a shell window. This will interrupt all ongoing chat sessions!

Projects to synchronize:
All projects are synchronized with the instant messaging services.
```

How can I correctly configure instant messaging in my server?

Answer (score 0):

try to connect to the service with a jabber client, to confirm that it is the jabber server which does not work or the widget in the instant messaging page.